# re-writing a getTickCount to work with Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Tags: excel, vba, attachmate-reflection

I hope you can help, I've moved over to a Windows 10 machine 64bit and one of the codes I used to interface with Attachmate no longer works as it is now reflection attachmate

The original code is

```vb
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Function screenCheckOK() As Boolean
    ' will wait for screen to become free. if not free after
    ' 30 seconds will return false

    Dim screenStatus As Integer
    Dim Start As Long
       
    screenCheckOK = False
    Start = GetTickCount()
    Do
        If GetTickCount() >= Start + 30000 Then Exit Function
        DoEvents
        screenStatus = getScreenStatus
    Loop Until screenStatus = 0
    screenCheckOK = True
End Function
```

Obviously I can't use `GetTickCount` I now have to use
`Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`.

But I just can't seem to write a new code for it. I thought I could use 'Sleep200 but that doesn't work.
any help please?

Comment: `Obviously I can't use GetTickCount` - why?

Comment: as I understand it GetTickCount will work with Attachmate and 32bit but not with Attachmate Reflection and 64bit. that's the issue I'm having, i'm trying the re-write the function to wait for the screen to become free and GetTickCount doesn't work